# Fatal error: Uncaught PDO Exception: SQLSTATE[42000] Syntax Error or Access Vilation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

I'm implementing a simple code to check if one email is already on my DB and if it is deleting it from the database. However, I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'@gmail.com' at line 1 in /home/saintpao/public_html/deleteNewsletter.php:24 Stack 
trace: #0 /home/saintpao/public_html/deleteNewsletter.php(24): 
PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/saintpao/public_html
/deleteNewsletter.php on line 24
```

This is the `conectar.php` file

```
$dbhost = "myHost";
$dbuser = "myUser";
$dbpass = "myPassword";
$dbname = "myDBName";
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass,  
                  array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(Exception $error) {
    die("Error conexión BBDD " . $error->getMessage());
}
```

And this is the `deleteNewsletter.php` file:

```
function sanitazeEmail($email){
   if(empty($email)){
       return "";
   }
   $sanitized = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
   if(filter_var($sanitized, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
       return $sanitized;
   }
   return "";
}

$success = false;
$email = sanitazeEmail($_POST['email']);

if(!empty($email)){
    require_once 'conectar.php';

    $sql = "SELECT `email` FROM `emails` WHERE `email` = " . $email;
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);

    if($statement->execute()){
        $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM `emails` WHERE `email` =" . $email;
        $statement = $db->prepare($sql_delete);
        $success = $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

The conection with the database works because I'm able to make  SELECT petition in other file, so it must be a problem with the `deleteNewsletter.php` file. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: When adding literal text to SQL statements which are strings, you need to have quotes round them.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: Would it be enough adding the following line to avoid SQL injection? `$statement->bindParam(':email', $email);`

Comment: @Jens Forgot to quote you on the last comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that the email is a string and should be quoted. But, you're using PDO and you could use prepared statements to avoid this kind of errors:

```
$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM `emails` WHERE `email` = :email";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql_delete);
$sucess = $statement->execute([':email' => $email]);
```

Note that your `select` query is not really useful, and you could just do the `delete` query. Note that `$statement->execute()` returns a statement, not the results.

As @NigelRen pointed out, you could use `$statement->rowCount()` to check if a row was deleted.

Comment: You could always call `rowCount ()` to check if a row was deleted.

Comment: I edited the post with the changes I made. Now I get the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in /home/saintpao/public_html/deleteNewsletter.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /home/saintpao/public_html/deleteNewsletter.php(23): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/saintpao/public_html/deleteNewsletter.php on line 23`

Comment: @Luiscri You missed the array in `execute()`.

Comment: What do you mean with that? @Syscall

Comment: Look at the execute call in the answer, there is an array with values, according to the placeholder in the query.

Comment: @Luiscri You can pass values using `execute($array_args)`, data will bound to the SQL statement (_"All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR"_).